# Disable input if checkbox is ticked on page load AND when it is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, input, disabled-input

I've looked at loads of questions that describe how to check weather a check box is checked or not but none of them gives the answer I need.  I want to check whether the check box is checked on page load and if it is, disable an input.  Then I need the disabled input to be changed when the box is checked/uncheked after page load.

This is what I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if ($('.is-repeat-event').prop('checked')) {
      $('.event-date').prop('disabled', 'true' );
    }
    $('.is-repeat-event').change(function(){
        var d = this.checked ? 'true' : 'false';
        $('.event-date').prop('disabled', d );
    });
});
```

either part on it's own works but putting them together doesn't work (the .change event has no effect on the input).

Comment: and if you treat true and false as booleans instead of strings?

Comment: Yep, that'll do it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is beacause property disabled need to set to boolean true/false values. also you can trigger the event after binding it to see the relevant changes in page load:

```
$('.is-repeat-event').change(function(){
   $('.event-date').prop('disabled', this.checked );
}).change();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, thats much nicer but it was the strings that were stopping the code from working

Comment: @Ralphonz: glad it helps. don't forget to upvote and accept helped answers

Answer (score 0):

Try using `trigger()`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.is-repeat-event').on('change', function(e) {
    $('.event-date').prop('disabled', this.checked);
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>Repeat
    <input type='checkbox' class="is-repeat-event" checked='' />
  </label>
</div>
Event Date
<input type='date' class="event-date" value="2015-07-12" />
```